# Set Meta key as KDE shortcut

Tags: kde-plasma

How to **set the Meta key as key shortcut** for something else than `Application Launcher` ? For example on `toggle present windows (all desktops)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar to your problem: I want to disable opening `Application Launcher` via Meta key (this too annoying for me).

Disable it with next:
`kwriteconfig5 --file kwinrc --group ModifierOnlyShortcuts --key Meta ""`